# Closing a Dialog with a WebView inside

Tags: android, webview, dialog

I have an `Dialog` which contains a `WebView`. When I no longer wish to display the `WebView`, I simply call `Dialog.cancel()`.

Is there any need to perform any cleaning of some sort on the `WebView`? I have seen a few references to calling `WebView.destroy()` but is that necessary? Will I end up having a memory leak if I don't properly dispose of the `WebView`?

Comment: With Java's garbage collection, when the parent dies, the children are supposed to die automatically. You might want to try dismiss() on the dialog too.

Comment: According to the docs, dismiss() and cancel() are the same however cancel() also calls it's onCancelListener. – Subby 5 mins ago